# Ubuntu 20.04 installation gets stuck

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, but during the installation setup before even configuring the drivers, it either keeps loading forever or freezes completely. I have a legacy system. I have a Intel CPU with Nvidia graphics card and I tried installing with safe graphics, but nothing seems to work. When I boot in the system I get this message, but the installation window still opens.

[image]

Comment: Any firmware updates? Try to install all such if available.

Comment: The laptop is quite old so most likely there are, but I know it's pretty dangerous to update and I was afraid

Comment: It might be the only way forward though.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO before making the Boot USB? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview Your screen shot does show a firmware bug. Where did you get it is dangerous to update your computer? References please. Edit the question and give the full hardware specs of the computer please.